# The Subclass of java.util.TreeMap gives NullPointerException on call put(key, value) method

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception, dictionary

I guess I might be missing something obvious here, but anyway lets see the code.

```
public static class FreeMap extends TreeMap<String, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer put(String key, Integer value) {
        out.println(super.toString());
        out.println(super.getClass().getName()+" "+key+" : "+value);
        int i = super.put(key, value);//line 227
        assert this.size() == 1;
        return i;
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FreeMap fm = new FreeMap();
    fm.put("A", 10);
}
```

On Running this you will get a output as following:

```
{}
com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.Graph$FreeMap A : 10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.Graph$FreeMap.put(Graph.java:227)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.Graph.main(Graph.java:212)
```

I can see super  is referring to FreeMap, not TreeMap, if it would have thrown a StackOverflow Exception I could have understood. Why nullpointerexception?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, because [`put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) returns the previous value:

> **Returns:**
>   the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)

There *is* no previous value, so it's returning `null`, which you're then unboxing, leading to an exception.

Given that your method is already declared to return `Integer`, the fix is easy. Change this:

```
int i = super.put(key, value);
```

to this:

```
Integer i = super.put(key, value);
```

Or ideally, for readability:

```
Integer oldValue = super.put(key, value);
```

Note that this would also be more efficient in the case that there *was* already a value for the key - there's no benefit from unboxing and reboxing.